# Get file size not working in scheduled job

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a bash script running on Ubuntu 18.04. I scheduled it using SYSTEMD timer.

```
    #!/bin/bash
backupdb(){
   /usr/bin/mysqldump -u backupuser -pbackuppassword --add-locks --extended-insert --hex-blob $1 > /opt/mysqlbackup/$1.sql
   /bin/gzip -c /opt/mysqlbackup/$1.sql > /opt/mysqlbackup/$1-$(date +%A).sql.gz
   rm -rf /opt/mysqlbackup/$1.sql
   echo `date "+%h %d %H:%M:%S"`": " $1 "- Size:" `/usr/bin/stat -c%s "${1}-$(date +%A).sql.gz"` >> /opt/mysqlbackup/backupsql.log
}

# List of databases to backup
backupdb cardb
backupdb bikedb
```

When I run this script interactively, the backup log get 2 entries:

```
Jun 16 20:15:03:  cardb - Size: 200345
Jun 16 20:15:12:  bikedb - Size: 150123
```

However, when this is run as a SYSTEMD timer service, the log still gets 2 entries but no file size is given in the log file. Not 0, it's simply blank. The backup file, cardb.sql.gz is created and is non-zero. I can unzip it and it does contain a valid SQL file.

I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Have you tried using the full path of the file in your call to the `stat` command?

Comment: You're not running it at 23:59:59 are you? :-)  Two suggestions: 1) Create a variable with the name of the zip and use that consistently (so if the backup starts on Tuesday but finishes on Wednesday your stat command is still good), 2) Sprinkle some "echo `date` "Zipping ${zip} >> /tmp/backup.log" commands through the script so that when you run from a timer you can see what is happening.  In the worst case, echo every command to the log, along with the date/time when it is run.

Comment: I see in your command `/usr/bin/stat -c%s "${1}-$(date +%A).sql.gz"` you do not specify a path to the .gz file. What directory are you in when you run this interactively? What directory are you in when you run this as a SYSTEMD timer service?

Comment: @ChrisBrownie55 &  SiKing, you both saw the error right off and here I've been banging my head on this forever. Thanks

Comment: Posted it as an answer then 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You need to specify the absolute path of your file

Without specifying the absolute path you are making the assumption that the systemd timer is running your script from the same directory you tested it from. To remedy this, you can either use the absolute path or change directories before accessing your file.

```sh
echo `date "+%h %d %H:%M:%S"`": " $1 "- Size:" `/usr/bin/stat -c%s "/opt/mysqlbackup/${1}-$(date +%A).sql.gz"` >> /opt/mysqlbackup/backupsql.log
```